# How can I create a view with duplicate columns and merge them?

Tags: mysql

I have pm_message tables with 1~9, and I want to create a view to simplified the process of MySQL query.

What I have is

```
CREATE VIEW `pm_messages` AS 
SELECT * FROM 
`pm_messages_0`, 
`pm_messages_1`, 
`pm_messages_2`, 
`pm_messages_3`,
`pm_messages_4`,
`pm_messages_5`,
`pm_messages_6`,
`pm_messages_7`,
`pm_messages_8`,
`pm_messages_9`;
```

I got error with douplicate column. There is no record is duplicate, I want to merge all of them in view, what should I do?

Comment: I think you can have a better solution instead of joining all of the tables, but try `union` instead of `,` like `SELECT * FROM  pm_messages_0 union pm_messages_1 union pm_messages_2 , ...`

Comment: Is your `pm_message tables with 1~9` tables are unique field??

Comment: Instead of a view, you can create a `UNION` table.

Comment: I strongly recommend you *test* the query you plan on storing as a view definition, *before* you run a create view statement. I also strongly suspect that the SELECT statement you have written does *not* return the   resultset you are looking for. The commas between the table names are join operators. With no join predicates, this is classic Cartesian product.  If each table contains 100 rows, the SELECT statement specifies a return of 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 rows (one trillion rows.) If any of the tables contains 0 rows, the query will return 0 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have coded a colossal cross join. Depending on the number of rows, it probably wouldn't return before the universe suffers entropy heat death.

I'm almost certain you want a *union*:

```
CREATE VIEW `pm_messages` AS 
SELECT * FROM `pm_messages_0` union all
SELECT * FROM `pm_messages_1` union all
SELECT * FROM `pm_messages_2` union all
SELECT * FROM `pm_messages_3` union all
SELECT * FROM `pm_messages_4` union all
SELECT * FROM `pm_messages_5` union all
SELECT * FROM `pm_messages_6` union all
SELECT * FROM `pm_messages_7` union all
SELECT * FROM `pm_messages_8` union all
SELECT * FROM `pm_messages_9`;
```

This will work if all tables have the same number and type of columns. If not, you'll have to explicitly select columns such that each select returns the same number and type of columns.